# Python csv's - next cell after a result is found

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have the code:

```
def checkdetails(username, password):
    with open('Data.csv', 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            if username == row[0]:
                #This is where i will need to check if the password in the next column matches
```

This searches through the csv's first column in order to see if the username exists. It works.

What i need it to do next is move along to the next column in that row and if it matches the value

Comment: So insidid of `if username == row[0]:` just do `if password == row[1]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
```